# How to handle failure on refresh token to avoid uncaught error

Tags: reactjs, jwt, refresh-token

I'm using that example, https://www.thedutchlab.com/insights/using-axios-interceptors-for-refreshing-your-api-token, to implement using of the refresh token in JWT application in React.

However, if using the refresh token fails for any reason, such error is not handled in the code presented in the link above. In React it causes uncaught error screen.

I've looked for other similar examples of using refresh token. They all look the same and such failure is not handled. How I should handle that in the code to redirect user to a login page without uncaught error showed?

Here's my code:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import TokenService from "./token";

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_API_URL,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    timeout: 5000
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
        const token = TokenService.getLocalAccessToken();
        if (token) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
        }
        return config;
    },
    (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

instance.interceptors.response.use(
    (res) => {
        return res;
    },
    async (err) => {
        const originalConfig = err.config;

        if (originalConfig.url !== "/login" && err.response) {
            if (err.response.status === 401 && !originalConfig.retry) {
                originalConfig.retry = true;

                try {
                    const response = await instance.post("/refreshtoken", {
                        "@ObjectType": "RefreshToken#1.0.0",
                        RefreshToken: TokenService.getLocalRefreshToken(),
                    });
                    TokenService.updateLocalAccessToken(response.data.Token);
                    TokenService.updateLocalRefreshToken(response.data.RefreshToken);

                    return instance(originalConfig);
                } catch (error) {
                    TokenService.removeUser();
                    window.location.replace(process.env.REACT_APP_FRONTEND_URL + '/#/login');
                }
            }
        }

        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
);

export default instance;
```

The problem is that even the script redirects to a login page as in the line `window.location.replace(process.env.REACT_APP_FRONTEND_URL + '/#/login')`, the uncaught error shows up on the screen like that:
[image: uncaucht-error]

Comment: Make sure you `try/catch` or use`.catch` block where it gets rejected and do the relevant action that is appropriate for you.

Comment: I did,  I relocated to login page.  What should I return after that to not propagate error?

Comment: You can create a function that fetches a new token using a refresh token in the background, without notifying users. If there is no refresh token available, redirect to the login page. In case the refresh operation fails, display an error message.
You can set a timer that refreshes it in advance before expiration.

Comment: You cam return an unresolved Promise along with window.location.replace, that should prevent the reject flow from hapenning. Therefore no error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

here is my approach, the redirection to the login screen is not a direct action but it's a result of losing session:

```
                // * when the AT is expired, so we need to get a new one (refresh)
                const newAccessToken = await refresh();
                // if the RT is expired, we won't find any AT, an this case a simple refresh (reload) must be enough to lose the session and get back to the login/home screen 
                if(!newAccessToken){
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                // * Normal process of attaching new AT and attaching it to interceptors
                prevRequest.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have always done this with code similar to the following, which could be translated to your preferred way of coding API requests, eg interceptors:

```js
private async callApi(path: string, method: Method, dataToSend?: any): Promise<any> {

    // Get the full path
    const url = `${this._apiBaseUrl}${path}`;

    // Get the access token, and if it does not exist a login redirect will be triggered
    let token = await this._authenticator.getAccessToken();

    try {

        // Call the API
        return await this._callApiWithToken(url, method, dataToSend, token);

    } catch (e: any) {

        // Report Ajax errors if this is not a 401
        if (e.statusCode !== 401) {
            throw e;
        }

        // If we received a 401 then try to refresh the access token
        token = await this._authenticator.refreshAccessToken();

        // The general pattern for calling an OAuth secured API is to retry 401s once with a new token
        return await this._callApiWithToken(url, method, dataToSend, token);
    }
}
```

If there is no access token yet, or if token refresh fails with an `invalid_grant` error code, I throw a [LoginRequired exception](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/errors/errorFactory.ts#L34). This error is treated specially by error presentation code, which avoids rendering it.

The user is then asked to re-authenticate, such as by updating `location.href`, and the user does not experience any errors. It is recommended to rehearse this expiry event, eg. by appending characters to the refresh token, to cause this error response.

I prefer the approach of a [service agent class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/api/client/fetchClient.ts#L35) to encapsulate plumbing such as response caching, custom headers and retries. Some people prefer the interceptor approach though.